# bootstrap nav tab is not highlighting the active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, i am using the following:-

1.bootstrap v2.0.4.

2.jQuery 1.11.2.

Inside the view i have proivde the following nav tabs:-

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">


    <li >@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Related Servers", "CustomerServer","Customer",
    new {customerID = Model.AccountDefinition.ORG_ID},
    new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "detail"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress",

 OnSuccess="detailsuccess",



}
)</li>

    <li >@Ajax.ActionLink("Show Related VMs", "CustomerVM","Customer",
    new {customerID = Model.AccountDefinition.ORG_ID},
    new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId = "detail"  ,
 LoadingElementId = "progress",
  OnSuccess="detailsuccess"


}
)</li>
```

where each of the Ajax.Actionlink will render a partial view when user clicks on it. currently when i move the mouse over a tab, the tab background color will change, but if i click on a tab and the partial view is rendered, the active tab will not be highlighted ..

i am referencing the following css files :-

```
<link id="bs-css" href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-cerulean.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='~/Content/css/opa-icons.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href="~/Content/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and the following scripts (in a ddtion to the jquery js of courde):-

```
<script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The active tab needs the

```
class="active"
```

class

Comment: i did not get ur point,,if i specify the following inside a tab , then it will always be highlighted even if the user did not click on it !!1

Comment: You can use jquery to add the class when the user clicks. And remove the class when the user clicks again.

Comment: can you adivce more on this ? and why this is not the case by defualt in Bootstrap ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the active class to the li element if you want it to be highlighted.
Example:

```
<li class="active">
```

Comment: but this will force the tab to always be highlighted,, while i need to highlight the tab which the user clicks on ...

Comment: You would need to remove the active class from the other element and add it to the element you want to be highlighted.